# maximum value of congestion window in ubuntu

Tags: congestion-control

Can anyone help me to find the max congestion window value for TCP in ubuntu? I only find the init window size; I can’t find the max.
I only can find the init window size . i need the max , it is related to buffer size of tcp ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to find the max congestion window value for TCP in ubuntu?

Command

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
```

will output something like

```
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    16384   4194304
```

the last value (4194304) is the maximum congestion window.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the send window.
With window scale option, you can find the  limits of send windows here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option

You may want to take a look into the actual implementation and may find the following useful:
1. general tcp implementation:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/net/ipv4/tcp.c
2.  TCP cubic variant:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/net/ipv4/tcp_cubic.c

The are various variants of TCP congestion control - you can find what flavour you are using based on: https://superuser.com/questions/992919/how-to-check-the-tcp-congestion-control-algorithm-flavour-in-ubuntu